# Why MPI and OpenMP Merge Sort are slower than my sequential code?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I have written a code for merge sort in C. I applied this algorithm in sequential, with OpenMP and with MPI. I used an array of 100 random elements.
The sequential code is the following:

```
int main(){
    int N = 100;
    int my_array[N];
    int outputArray[N];
    int length = sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]);
    double start_time, end_time;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        my_array[i]=rand()%100 + 1;
    }
    //print the array 
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", my_array[i]);
    }   

    printf("\n--------------\n");
    start_time = MPI_Wtime();
    mergeSort(my_array, 0, length-1, outputArray); 
    end_time = MPI_Wtime();
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", my_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n Tempo impiegato: %f ", (end_time - start_time));
} 


void merge(int arr[], int indexA, int indexB, int end, int arrOut[]){
    int i=indexA, j=indexB, k=indexA;
    while(i<=indexB-1 && j<=end){
        if(arr[i]<arr[j]){
            //i=i+1;
            arrOut[k]=arr[i++];
        }
        else{
            //j=j+1;
            arrOut[k]=arr[j++];
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<=indexB-1){
        //i++;
        arrOut[k]=arr[i++];
        k++;
    }
    while(j<=end){
        //j++;
        arrOut[k]=arr[j++];
        k++;
    }
    for(i=indexA; i<=end; i++)
        arr[i]=arrOut[i];
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[]){
    int medium;
    if(inf<sup){
        medium=(inf+sup)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, inf, medium, arrOut);
        mergeSort(arr, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
        merge(arr, inf, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
    }
}
```

Then, the implementation with MPI is the following (it start just after the creation of the random array):

```
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n_ranks);
    start_time = MPI_Wtime();

    size=N/n_ranks;
    sub_array=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    temp=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    MPI_Scatter(my_array, size, MPI_INT, sub_array, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    mergeSort(sub_array, 0, length-1, temp);
    MPI_Gather(sub_array, size, MPI_INT, outputArray, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank==0){
        int *temp_array=malloc(N*sizeof(int));
        mergeSort(outputArray, 0, length-1, temp_array);
        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("%d ", temp_array[i]);
        }
        free(temp_array);
    }

    //free(&my_array);
    free(sub_array);
    free(temp);

    //MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    end_time = MPI_Wtime();
```

EDITED CODE OPENMP: And finally this is with OpenMP (the main is the same)

```
void parallelMergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[], int level){
    if (level==0){
        #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp single
        parallelMergeSort(arr, inf, sup, arrOut, 1);
    }
    else if(level<8){
        #pragma omp task shared(arr, arrOut)
        {
            parallelMergeSort(arr, inf, (inf+sup)/2, arrOut, level+1);
        }
        #pragma omp task shared(arr, arrOut)
        {
            parallelMergeSort(arr, (inf+sup)/2 + 1, sup, arrOut, level+1);
        }
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
    {
        mergeSort(arr, inf, sup, arrOut);
    }   
}
```

If I apply these code to an array of 100 elements, the time of execution is higher for the MPI and OpenMP code.
Time sequential: 0.000044

Time OpenMP: 0.00949953

Time MPI: 0.003077

Edit: If I try with 10^6 random elements, results are these:

Time sequential: 0.899016

Time OpenMP: Segmentation error

Time MPI: 25.625195
How can I improve these results?

Comment: Are you sure sorting consecutive sorted subarrays is faster than sorting the initial array? if not, improve your algorithm as suggested in your previous question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I edited the post with time spent for an array of 10^6 elements

Comment: Read [this](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S16/notes/Lecture03/cme323_lec3.pdf) and [this](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S16/notes/Lecture04/cme323_lec4.pdf) about parallel MergeSort.

Comment: The OpenMP version does not give correct result even if 1 thread is used only. First you should correct the code.

Comment: The OpenMP level==0 needs to go, and the other levels you need to create two tasks.

Comment: Yes @VictorEijkhout you are right! Can you explain me why I had to remove level 0?

Comment: There is no point in doing level 0 separately. You want to split every level in two, except when it gets too small. I understand that you do that level separately because it has the parallel/single combo. You should put those pragmas outside the top level call to `parallelMergeSort`.

Comment: No, sorry, it does not work. level=0 prevents from having segmentation error, but the result is wrong

Comment: So, you mean, remove the pragmas from the `parallelMergeSort` and insert in the main just before calling the function?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout You are talking about how to use OpenMP pragmas, but @CassellaJr is not there yet. If all the pragmas are removed, the result are still wrong... BTW: I think using `level==0` is not efficient, but should work, another problem that you did not mention is that there is no synchronisation (wait for the the task to finish) in the code....

Comment: I have no idea where is the problem in this code, why it does not sort the array...

Comment: Moreover, this morning OpenMP with 100 elements worked, in the sense that the array was sorted. The I do not know what I changed ;(

Comment: As @Laci remarked, there are more problems, such as that you don't wait for the tasks to finish. If the result is correct, that may be coincidence.

Comment: I edited the original post with the wait, now it sorted an array of 100 in the correct way

Comment: So now there are big problems in my OpenMP code? 10^6 elements are sorted in 5 seconds, while in sequential code only 1 seconds

Comment: The same for MPI, 25 seconds for 10^6 elements... but I will happy If I fix well the openMP code, then I there is time to work on MPI :)

Comment: How about using this check also in OpenMP version `if(inf<sup){...` and using 2 separate tasks for the 2 `parallelMergeSort` calls?

Comment: The check `if(inf<sup)` is already in the `mergeSort` function. Do you mean that I have to write it again? Where?

Comment: I have understood the part of using 2 separate tasks for the calls, and yes, the time decreased to 0.233939! I updated the post with the last code that I have

Comment: Btw, remove the OpenMPI tag from your question. This question is generic to all MPI versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know MPI, so I only answer the OpenMP part of the question.
Without changing the algorithm, the OpenMP version of your `mergeSort` function should look something like this:

```
void parallelMergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[], int level){
    if(inf<sup){
        int medium=(inf+sup)/2;
        #pragma omp task shared(arr, arrOut) if(level>0)
          parallelMergeSort(arr, inf, medium, arrOut, level-1);   
        parallelMergeSort(arr, medium+1, sup, arrOut, level-1);
        #pragma omp taskwait
         merge(arr, inf, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
    }
}
```

I have used the `if(level>0)` clause to avoid starting too much tasks. On my computer using `level=4` gives the shortes runtimes, but of course it depends on the number of cores available and on the size of the array. Note that I did not use a second `#pragma omp task` line before the second `parallelMergeSort` function call, because it will run faster this way. You should call this function using:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
parallelMergeSort(my_array, 0, length-1, outputArray,4);
```

If you whish to change the algorithm for better parallelization, please read the documents I have linked in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the links. That merge function is already tricky to write sequentially, but it is the main impediment to parallelization. Quicksort has the same problem, and many naive tutorials on parallelization ignore that.